# How to calculate the rank of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> I need to calculate the rank of the matrix $A$, shown below:
>   $$ 
> A=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 3 & 2 & -1\\
> 2 & -3 & -5\\
> -1 & -4 &- 3
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

---

I know that I need to calculate $\det(A)$ and if $\det(A) \neq 0$ then the rank will be equal to $3$, but in this case I'm required to zero-out first column of matrix $A$ using element $a_{31} = -1$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use `row reduction`: the rank is the number of non-zero rows after you've performed row reduction:
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
3&2&-1\\2&-3&-5\\-1&-4&-3
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&4&3\\3&2&-1\\2&-3&-5
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&4&3\\0&-10&-10\\0&-11&-11
\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]
\rightsquigarrow&\begin{bmatrix}
1&4&3\\0&1&1\\0&-11&-11
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&4&3\\0&1&1\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Thus, the rank is $2$.

Note that it was obvious after the second step.

Answer (score 13):

The second column - first column is the last column so the rank is $<3$.

The first two colums are linearly independent so the rank is $2$.

Answer (score 10):

The key word is [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

Comment: This. I searched way too much for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply linear transformations to $A$ and find an upper triangular matrix. The number of non-zero lines of that matrix will give you the rank of $A$